# Close an Excel file was opened in Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

My code needs to open an Excel file (with formulas) to search for a given value and close this file, will do some calculations and will write the answer in this file.
  I can not get Matlab to close the file before it writes the response and this error appears:
Error using xlswrite (line 226)
The file C: \Temp\Data_Home.xlsx is not writable. It might be locked by another process.

```
File_123 = 'C: \Temp\Data_Home.xlsx';
xlObj = actxserver('Excel.Application');            %Start Excel
wsObj = xlObj.Workbooks.Open(File_123);             %Open workbook
Sheet = wsObj.Sheets.Item(3);                       %Assume we're using the first sheet
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Quit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/com.quit.html) and [`delete`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delete.html) as mentioned in the example in the documentation of [`actxserver`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/actxserver.html#d117e7180).

```
Quit(xlObj);
delete(xlObj);
```

Comment: Fantastic... 
Thanks